# How to change label distance in a TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to TikZ, so please excuse some stupidity on my side.

I'd like to TikZ a tower of fields, however the distance of the inner labels and the edges is too big. I'd like to reduce that. Is there a simple way of achieving that, without rewriting the whole code? I searched for answers before, but all questions I found were either slightly different, or the answers digressed into complete and utter complexity (at least for me).

Here's a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                        % use T1 fonts for font encoding
\usepackage{amsfonts}                           % math font
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Fr}{\textbf{F}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
      \node (F3)                                      {$\F_3$};
      \node (F33) [above of=F3,  left of=F3]          {$\F_{3^3}$};
      \node (F32) [above of=F3,  right of=F3]         {$\F_{3^2}$};
      \node (F36) [above of=F3,  node distance = 4cm] {$\F_{3^6}$};
      \node (F318)[above of=F33, node distance = 4cm] {$\F_{3^{18}}$};
      \node (F39) [above of=F33, left of=F33]         {$\F_{3^9}$};
      \draw[-] (F3)  to node        {3} (F33);
      \draw[-] (F3)  to node [swap] {2} (F32);
      \draw[-] (F32) to node [swap] {3} (F36);
      \draw[-] (F33) to node        {2} (F36);
      \draw[-] (F33) to node        {3} (F39);
      \draw[-] (F36) to node [swap] {3} (F318);
      \draw[-] (F39) to node        {2} (F318);
      \draw (F3)  to node [swap] {$\langle \Fr \rangle$}  (F33);
      \draw (F3)  to node        {$\langle \Fr \rangle$}  (F32);
      \draw (F32) to node        {$\langle \Fr^2 \rangle$}(F36);
      \draw (F33) to node [swap] {$\langle \Fr^3\rangle$} (F39);
      \draw (F33) to node [swap] {$\langle \Fr^3\rangle$} (F36);
      \draw (F36) to node        {$\langle \Fr^6\rangle$} (F318);
      \draw (F39) to node [swap] {$\langle \Fr^9\rangle$} (F318);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An clumpsy solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                        % use T1 fonts for font encoding
\usepackage{amsfonts}                           % math font
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Fr}{\textbf{F}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2cm, auto,
every node/.style = {inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt},
vrtc/.style = {inner sep=3pt}]
      \node (F3)  [vrtc]                                    {$\F_3$};
      \node (F33) [vrtc,above of=F3,  left of=F3]          {$\F_{3^3}$};
      \node (F32) [vrtc,above of=F3,  right of=F3]         {$\F_{3^2}$};
      \node (F36) [vrtc,above of=F3,  node distance = 4cm] {$\F_{3^6}$};
      \node (F318)[vrtc,above of=F33, node distance = 4cm] {$\F_{3^{18}}$};
      \node (F39) [vrtc,above of=F33, left of=F33]         {$\F_{3^9}$};
      \draw[-] (F3)  to node        {3} (F33);
      \draw[-] (F3)  to node [swap] {2} (F32);
      \draw[-] (F32) to node [swap] {3} (F36);
      \draw[-] (F33) to node        {2} (F36);
      \draw[-] (F33) to node        {3} (F39);
      \draw[-] (F36) to node [swap] {3} (F318);
      \draw[-] (F39) to node        {2} (F318);
      \draw (F3)  to node [swap] {$\langle \Fr \rangle$}  (F33);
      \draw (F3)  to node        {$\langle \Fr \rangle$}  (F32);
      \draw (F32) to node        {$\langle \Fr^2 \rangle$}(F36);
      \draw (F33) to node [swap] {$\langle \Fr^3\rangle$} (F39);
      \draw (F33) to node [swap] {$\langle \Fr^3\rangle$} (F36);
      \draw (F36) to node        {$\langle \Fr^6\rangle$} (F318);
      \draw (F39) to node [swap] {$\langle \Fr^9\rangle$} (F318);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
    \end{document}
```

In above code I reduce inner separation of all nodes to 1pt and define node `vrtc`, where I return it to 3pt.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. But why do you define a new node instead of just using

every node/.style = {inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt}

and leaving it at that?

Comment: @sblasher, special node for diagram nodes (vertices)  I determine because  otherwise the edges comes to close to text in them. If this doesn't disturbing you, you can simply omit it definition in TikZ setup and its use in picture.

Comment: Okay, that explains it. Thanks for the help.